# Computing a Transformation then visualizing with TransformedRegion Function

Tags: regions, visualization, indexing

I have some function $\psi$, I compute the transformation $T = \vec{x} - \nabla \psi$. I'd like to visualize the action of $T$ on a square centered at the origin.

The mathematica website shows some examples of how to compute transformations.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html

I have two questions:

1. If I want to subimpose the initial region (perhaps in red) under the final region, how would I do this? Also I'd like to add coordinate axes.
2. Below is included a sketch of code. How do I get the coordinates of the gradient I compute into the transformation function. Below is my best guess, but I'm totally lost on how to accomplish this.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
psi = -4 (x^2 + y^2);
gradPsi = Grad[psi, {x, y}]; /. {Indexed[#, 1] -> x , 
  Indexed[#, 2] -> y}
R = 
  TransformedRegion[
   Rectangle[], {Indexed[#, 1] - Indexed[gradPsi, 1], 
     Indexed[#, 2] + Indexed[gradPsi, 2]} &];
Region[R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
psi = -4 (x^2 + y^2);

gradPsi = Grad[psi, {x, y}]

R = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], {Indexed[#, 1] - First@gradPsi /. x -> #[[1]], 
     Indexed[#, 2] + Last@gradPsi /. y -> #[[2]]} &];

Show[Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Blue, Rectangle[]}], 
 RegionPlot[R, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red]], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there, thanks!! I meant to say the center of the square is centered at the origin. I think this is the bottom left corner. I'm having a little trouble interpreting the picture. For the example I showed, the Transformation should blow up a box whose center is at the origin by a factor of 9. $T = \langle x - (-8x), y - (-8y) \rangle$

Comment: Ah got it, thanks! There's a typo in the formula, and the box can be recentered using documentation.